# How do you query the current value of WKInterfaceSlider in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

How do you get the current value of a WKInterfaceSlider in Swift?  I can't find it in the docs anywhere?  I can get the value when the slider is changed, however how to I query its state upon initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many WatchKit objects, to save battery life, this object doesn't allow you to *get* values.

Since you set the initial value (either with `setValue(_:)` or in your storyboard), and you're informed in the action method when it changes, you should always know it.

If you'll need to access it later, save the initial value in your data model and update it when the slider changes.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that was bugging the heck out of me not being able to find it.  Not sure why you're not able to query it still.  Maybe later versions will allow.  I know that technically if I set it in Interface Builder then I can hard code its initial value, however I would really like to query it as you can query the value everything else.  Guess I'll submit a feature request.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume it will come in a later version, but the API design is to reduce communications between the iPhone and the watch by forcing you to cache as much as possible on the iPhone side.

Comment: @AaronBrager sorry that doesnt make sense to me.. yes the action method will get triggered but how do you know if the user increased to decreased the value? therefore you won't always know the value?

Comment: @4GetFullOf Read what I wrote: *"If you'll need to access it later, save the initial value in your data model and update it when the slider changes."*

Comment: @AaronBrager yes sorry I never noticed the action returns the value with every trigger